# What is the correct syntax year(date_column) = year(getdate())?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to add a value for a label.

I get this ERROR:

> date1_column is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

```
int sum;
conn.Open()
var cmd = new SqlCommand( 
    "SELECT 
        (
            SELECT ISNULL(SUM(number1_column), 0) 
            FROM table1_name 
            WHERE 
                YEAR(date1_column) = YEAR(getdate()) 
                AND MONTH(date1_column) = MONTH(getdate())
        ) 
        - (
            SELECT ISNULL(SUM(number2_column), 0) 
            FROM table2_name 
            WHERE 
                YEAR(date2_column) = YEAR(getdate()) 
                AND MONTH(date2_column) = MONTH(getdate()) 
        )
    ",
    conn
);

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {
    sum = (int)reader[0];
    label.Text = sum.ToString();
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: what is your db compatible level? try with  SELECT compatibility_level  
--FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'yourdbname';

Answer (score 2):

If you want rows where your date is in this month then the better logic is use `>=` and `<` logic, as it keeps your query SARGable:

```
WHERE YourDateColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,GETDATE()),0)
  AND YourDateColumn < DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.sum_number1_column, 0) -
       COALESCE(t2.sum_number2_column, 0)
FROM (SELECT SUM(number1_column) as sum_number1_column
      FROM table1_name 
      WHERE date1_column >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) AND
            date1_column < dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
     ) t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(number2_column) as sum_number2_column
      FROM table2_name 
      WHERE date2_column >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) AND
            date2_column < dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
     ) t2;
```

There are several parts to this answer.

First, the subqueries are moved to the `FROM` clause.  This is a convenience, actually, to handle the `NULL` values.  Each subquery will return exactly one row, even if no rows match the `WHERE` clause.

Second, this handles `NULL` values that are returned because there are no rows in the underlying tables.  Your version does not do that.  The `NULL` needs to be handled *after* the subquery returns.  I find this simpler with `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT`.

Third, the date arithmetic uses `datefromparts()`, a very handy SQL Server function.  This means that there is no mysterious date transformations.  And, the resulting code can use an index on the date column.